# AudioKit 5 in Xcode 12 MIDI openInput() not working

Tags: swift, xcode, midi, audiokit

I'm trying to create a simple swift app that receives MIDI inputs, but I can't get the `receivedMIDINoteOn()` working. i.e. no `received a note on` was printed in the console.

I tried to debug and found that the **inputports** has one entry: "**key** =    Int32   1263786875, **value** = UInt32  0".

What did I missed?

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit
import CoreMIDI
import Cocoa

class MIDIHardwareListener: MIDIListener {
    
    let midi = AudioKit.MIDI()
    
    init() {
        midi.openInput()
        midi.addListener(self)
        availableInputs = MIDIHardwareListener.listInputs()
        print("available inputs: \(availableInputs)") // this prints out: ["Roland Digital Piano"]
    }

    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID?, offset: MIDITimeStamp) {
        print("received a note on")
    }
    // ...other protocol required functions
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from what you provided, but is it possible that the MIDI input is not available yet when you open the input? In the AudioKit Cookbook, there's a MIDI Monitor that I just verified is working.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Hi, thanks for your comment. I was playing with another AudioKit project "MIDIAnalyser" by T-Bre on GitHub.  His project works fine to receive my MIDI input data. However, his code was based on AudioKit 4.x. I also checked the "MIDI Monitor" in the Cookbook, but it's for "Bluetooth device on IOS", not tested with "USB connection on Mac" (which is my case) yet.

Comment: Sure, but can you try adding a button to do the MIDI.openInput() to see if its an availability issue?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I added a button to run the" MIDI.openInput()" but it doesn't help. I can get the device name and UID, but can't receive any inputs from it.

Comment: Can you share the project? This process works for me.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I uploaded the project to git: [link](https://github.com/peirisyin/pianoMidiTest) It's a very simple project.